# On deleting extended SP2013 web application it gives "HTTP 404 Not Found Error" for all SP2013 sites including central admin?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I was extending an SP2013 web application (ie-"`http://sp13dev:3030"`), and I used existing IIS website with port 80. And when I deleted that extended web application with port 80 of site `"http://sp13dev:3030"`. It started throwing an error to all SharePoint sites on that server it is throwing "`HTTP 404 Not Found Error`" for all the sites. And as I was doing changes to see the issue, all the sharepoint sites are opening through localhost. Please can anybody tell what would be the issue.

Comment: Check the IIS on the server and see if there are any bindings left for central admin and the other web applications. Did you delete the whole web application or just the IIS site from SharePoint?

Comment: No I just deleted the extended web application. And it created a mess. There are no any extra bindings for central admin or any other application and those created by me I deleted them.

Comment: Are the applications pool up and running? Did the binding get removed for the web application in IIS?

Comment: yes application pools are running. And I removed that binding for web application which I was working.

Comment: add the server name in alternate access mapping and see

Comment: Central administration is not opening I can't go at that page.

Comment: how many web application you have? You created web app on sp13dev:3030 then extend it on port 80, right? what you mean by using the exisitng IIS website?

Comment: We want the same content db with the UI changed so we are doing that.

Comment: Hello Waqas, it just happened after extending it through powershell. It is showing that web.config file in Content View.

Comment: Can you tell me how to extend the web applicaiton for two front end servers. Means the application that I am extending on one front end server is present on another. How can I extend it?